# Undefined reference to a static local variable

Tags: c++, static, g++, c++11

This is the simplest example I could come up with that reproduces the problem.

```
template<class T>
struct X
{
    static void foo()
    {
        static int z = 0;
        []{ z = 1; }();
    }
};

int main()
{
    X<int>::foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried it with MinGW 4.6 and 4.7, also g++ 4.6 in Ubuntu and all of them give me the link error "undefined reference to `z'". So now that makes me wonder if this is even legal. VC10 has no problem with it.

It works if X is normal class instead of a template. Also, I don't think it's related to lambdas cause I get the error even if I replace the lambda with a local class.

Comment: add c++11 tag, maybe it will give you better response

Answer (score 10, accepted):

g++ accepts the following, but VC++ does not:

```
[&z]{ z = 1; }();
```

Here `z` is being captured so g++ does not complain about an *undefined reference*. However:

> **5.1.2/10:**
>
> The identifiers in a capture-list are looked up using the usual rules for unqualified name lookup (3.4.1); each such lookup shall find
>   a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching
>   scope of the local lambda expression.

`z` is *not* automatic storage. `z` can therefore not be captured. g++ behavior is therefore incorrect, and VC++ is correct.

In your code, that VC++ accepts and g++ does not:

```
[]{ z = 1; }();
```

`z` is accessed by VC++ as static storage, which is allowed in a lambda body. g++ apparently does not resolve the name `z` to the static variable declared above and therefore throws *undefined reference*, while it shouldn't.

**tl;dr**
It's probably a bug in g++

**Edit:**
[It is indeed a bug](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.bugs/334029) and is fixed in 4.7.

Comment: Nice: it might even explain why TonyK's work around actually works, though I am not sure whether the "reference to z" would have automatic storage. Looking up 5.2.1/9, one also notes that the "reaching scope" your note refers to stops at the innermost enclosing function, thus also excluding "globals" (which do not have automatic storage duration anyway). So it seems fully intended that the capture list may only capture local variables by copy.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why it works for normal classes and not for templates. But you can get your example to work if you capture the local variable `z` by reference:

```
static void foo()
{
    static int z = 0;
    [&z]{ z = 1; }(); // Note: [&z]
}
```

Wikipedia has more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B).

Comment: Someone named @cicada posted the same answer but then she deleted it (now you're here with same answer) , don't know why did she delete it 0_o

Comment: @Mr.Anubis because I'm still trying to figure out why g++ behaves differently than VC++

Comment: @Cicada Both compilers are free to behave differently when one possibly have bug and another doesn't.

Comment: @Cicada: g++ is definitely bugged, at least as far as lambda support goes. Changing the capture list from `[&z]` to `[&]` reawakens the same error as the OP, which is at least inconsistent (regardless of the Standard). I also think (according to your answer) that VC++ is bugged since it accepts the code.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I suppose VC++ is accessing `z` as a static-storage variable which is allowed (and correct). I'll edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @Cicada: I don't see any provision for static-storage variables in the Standard, mind pointing it out to me ?

Comment: You cannot capture static variables.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The lambda body (called `compound-statement` in the grammar) behaves as a `function-body` if my understanding is correct, and thus static variables can be accessed from within. See 5.1.2/7.

Comment: @Cicada: I would read this as meaning that a local static variable can be created in the lambda, and not as allowing the lambda body to access local static in a surrounding function.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I read it as "a lambda body is allowed to do anything that a normal function body can do." [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293603.aspx) seems to agree with this interpretation (Lambda Body section). We can chat about this if you wish!

Comment: @Cicada: there is no static variable accessed from within the lambda body in the MSDN example. `x` and `y` have automatic storage duration. We may chat if you wish, but I have little else to say, I am definitely no authority on the subject (unlike Johannes).